# AWS OpenSearch cluster is down: /_cluster/health: {"message":null}

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

I have an AWS ElasticSearch Service (now "OpenSearch") domain and use it for low volume development.  All of a sudden, it is down and I get the following for cluster status:

> /_cluster/health: {"message":null}

Since this is a "managed service," there is no way to restart the cluster.

Since I have the basic support plan, I would have to pay $30/month to get support.

This is crap. Ideas?

Comment: Try to reconfigure the cluster (change node size)?

Comment: I tried upgrading to OpenSearch 1.0 and it has been "Performing Engine Upgrade" for hours. I wonder if it will ever end.  Is this what I should expect from a serverless OpenSearch service or should I look for another service provider?

Comment: That's definitely not normal for AWS. You would probably get better support on Elastic Cloud though.

Comment: For the record, the upgrade never completed and I was not able to figure how to report this error in the AWS OpenSearch platform without paying money. Surprising and terrible failure of this new service.

Comment: I ended up deleting the domain, losing all my data, creating a new domain and reindexing everything.  I'll find another service before production. Beware.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on my AWS OpenSearch domain having one node of type `t3.medium.search`. Actually, the node was down.

Under notifications for that domain, I found that the node was low on shards.

I increased the shards from 1000 to 1500 as mentioned here, [Choosing the number of shards for OpenSearch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/sizing-domains.html#bp-sharding), using the below query via Kibana:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
   "persistent":{
      "cluster.max_shards_per_node": 1500
   }
}
```

Also, I changed the number of replicas for all indexes from 1 to 0 so that the OpenSearch must not migrate shards on other nodes for high availability. I did this using the below query via Kibana:

```
PUT /*/_settings
{
  "index" : {
    "number_of_replicas" : 0
  }
}
```

Where `my-index-dev-*` will be replaced by the actual index pattern.

After a few minutes, the OpenSearch domain was healthy again.

***Note: Don't set the number of replicas to zero in the production environment as you may have more than 1 node.***